# How to map Alt-Enter

Tags: key-bindings

I'm using gnome-terminal, which uses 7-bit input. This means Vim's meta/alt keys, e.g. `<M-f>` don't work without some extra configuration. I know how to set that up for normal keys, like <kbd>F</kbd>, but not for <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> the terminal sends `^[` `F`, where the `^[` is a single Escape byte (`\x1b`). I can make `<M-f>` usable by doing:

```
set  <F13>=^[f
map  <F13> <M-f>
map! <F13> <M-f>
```

How can I do this for the Enter key (`<CR>`)?

Comment: did you try `set  <a-cr>=^[^M` ?

Comment: @Mass I did not, until you mentioned it, and it works! You should submit that as an answer and I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: @Mass The next question is how to map `Alt+Shift+Enter`...

Comment: It looks like gnome-terminal sends the same byte sequence for `Alt+Shift+Enter` as for `Alt+Enter` so I won't be able to use `<M-S-CR>`, at least not on this terminal. On a more configurable term like Alacritty I can though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On many terminals (specifically the ones that send alt-modified keys as `escape` then `key`), you can map alt+enter in the same way as many other alt combinations,

```
set <a-cr>=^[^M
```

This is two characters- escape then control m.  Alternatively,

```
execute "set <a-cr>=\<esc>\<cr>"
```

Then you can then use `<a-cr>` in maps;

```
nnoremap <a-cr> something
```

There is no standard way to map `alt+shift+enter`, or indeed any other `alt+shift+` combination.  Also, if your terminal supports it, you will have to use one of the unused F keys, e.g. `<f13>` through `<f37>` on linux (since there's no `<s-c-cr>` key code in vim) set to your terminal's proprietary escape sequence.

```
set <f25>=...
```

For example, my terminal sends escape, escape, then OM (four characters):

```
set <f25>=^[^[OM
```

Comment: There are even more unused Function keys beyond F26, though they're undocumented, They seem to go up to 37.

Comment: Good catch.  Indeed, the number 37 is pretty mysterious.

Comment: For neovim the command should be `map <a-cr>`, the `set ...` semantic will output error: `Unknown option: set`.